# Unity4 and Prime31 Game Center Plug-in Event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-center

I'm still new when it comes to C# programming (I normally use Unityscript). I have the Game Center plugin up and running successfully, except for one thing...

When an achievement is accomplished, the banner appears as it should to say the Achievement is unlocked from Game Center. However, if the same requirements for that Achievement are met again during another game, the banner appears again, even though it's already been fulfilled.

Now I've been told that I should getAchievements() to update my list of achievements met, and to read the data, i should "loop through this event":

```
public static event Action<List<GameCenterAchievement>> achievementsLoaded;
```

Problem is, I have no idea how to loop through the event. This is the only feedback I've received despite several desperate pleas for help on the topic on the unity forums.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the original answer meant was that you should loop through the list of achievements returned by that event. For more familiarity with events and how they work please see the [MSDN Events Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Essentially you will want to associate a function with the appropriate signature with that event by appending it to the subscribers list. That association will look something like this:

```
achievementsLoaded += (list) =>
{
    foreach(var achievement in list)
    {
         ....
    }
}
```

Or, if you'd prefer to use a member function:

```
void achievementsLoadedSubscriber(List<GameCenterAchievement> list)
{
    foreach(var achievement in list)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

in your class body. Then, elsewhere when you are setting up the system:

```
achievementsLoaded += achievementsLoadedSubscriber;
```

Notice the lack of parentheses because you are literally adding the function itself to the list, not calling the function.

Comment: Thanks - I do understand this part and it's what I have in my scripts. However I have another member called "public static void ReportAchievement (string id)" which I call when an achievement has been accomplished in game. I send to it the Achievement id (as appears in itunes) to trigger the achievement success. What I don't get is how can i first check that the achievement is already accomplished or not using the method "achievementsLoadedSubscriber" In my code I'm using for each to search for achievement.identity and achievement.completed > how do i get this info to ReportAchievement method?

Comment: Thanks Dave K for your answer above... It's helped me to find the answer and resolve the issue.